# "__attribute__((always_inline))" not working as expected?

Tags: c, xcode, inline, xcode4.6

```
static inline int my_function() __attribute__((always_inline));

static inline int my_function()
{
     //...
}
```

So I have declared my function as above although in the binary the function is branched to and not inlined, therefore a simple NOP could render the whole function useless.

[image]

How can I force Xcode 4.6 to inline the function?

Comment: You can't force Xcode to inline the function, since Xcode doesn't compile your code. Perhaps you want to ask the **compiler** to inline it, right?

Comment: Yes you're right, I hoped by including which IDE i was using people answering would know the compiler and version to which they could suggest possible build setting flags to be entered into Xcode.

Comment: Show us the definition of `my_function`.

Comment: @user1763532 Cool. Are you sure you have marked the **definition** as `always_inline` as well? Does the compiler see the declaration at the time it encounters the definition?

Comment: I hope you don't have declared your function with an interface like that: return type of `int` and never returning anything, and as receiving an unspecified number of arguments? But if so, you should first fix that to help the compiler to know what to put at the point of call, and then see again. Also do you compile with all optimization enabled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function as you give it here has no prototype: you don't provide the type of the arguments. In C just having `()` in the declaration means that the function receives an unknown number of arguments. Probably the compiler then supposes not to know enough about the function to inline it. Use `(void)` to declare a function without arguments.

Comment: Sorry, I simplified the code to highlight how I had declared it was inline. It of course returns an integer otherwise it would have been declared as a return type of void. The problem was with my_function() calling a recursive function, which the complier wouldn't have been able to inline anyway. Thanks though, I will be using (void) for the args from now on.